# Removing a digit from a number, Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Table Employee:**

```
Id  Name  Salary
--  ----  ------
1   A1    120
2   B1    105
3   C1    200
```

Now I want to find the **Sum of Salary**, by removing the 0s in salary of each employee.

i.e ; 12 + 15 + 2 = 29

Any idea on how to achieve my result ?

Thanks

Comment: What datatype is Salary?

Comment: Salary is Integer type.

Comment: Why? I sure hope that is not how my salary is calculated!!!

Comment: Got this as a coding question at hackerrank . The 0 key in a user's keyboard didn't work while he was entering the data it seems. I have to find the error amount (  difference between the actual total salary and the total salaries without 0s included in each of them ) . Strange question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If `Salary` is of numeric type, you need to `CAST` it first to `VARCHAR`. Then use `REPLACE` to get rid of the `0`s and then `CAST` it back to a numeric type before finally doing a `SUM`:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CAST(REPLACE(CAST(Salary AS VARCHAR(10)), '0', '') AS INT))
FROM Employee
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(REPLACE(t.Salary, '0', '') AS INT))
FROM (
    VALUES (120),(105),(200)
) t(Salary)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select ceil(avg(salary) - avg(replace(salary,'0',''))) from employees;
```

or you can simply use replace function

Answer (score 0):

This code should work too:

```
sum(replace(salary,"0",""))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT ROUND (AVG(Salary) - 
        AVG(CONVERT(INTEGER, REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, Salary), 0, ''))), 0 )
FROM EMPLOYEES
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.  In particular, why do you use `AVG` rather than `SUM`?